# WPF Rotate object before main animation loop

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I'm trying to understand rules of WPF animation usying code from this site:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23257/Beginner-s-WPF-Animation-Tutorial

Now I have a code to rotate element around x, y point:

```cs
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform();

DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();

da.From = 0;
da.To = 360;
da.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
da.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
image.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(x, y);
image.RenderTransform = rt;
rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, da);
```

This is GIF image like "^", so I want to rotate it 90 deg BEFORE animation to rotate image like ">".

`Tried RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(90);` but no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you also change the `From` property of `da` from 0 to 90?

Comment: `da.From = 90;`

Comment: If you want to start off with the element rotated already you could try a layouttransform with a rotatetransform of 90 degrees angle. In addition to your animation.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting the `Angle` property of `rt` to `90`, you should also change the `From` property of `da` to `90` to start animating from this value:

```
RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(90);
...
da.From = 90;
```

Comment: Or do not set `From` at all. Then it will start from the current value, i.e. 90.